# flatten  nested and include javascript files

Tags: javascript, css, flat-file

Is there a tool (maybe option in V8 engine) that takes JavaScript source and convert it to 
one big JavaScript flatten file? and also for CSS include files?

Comment: what do you mean by "flatten"? *did you mean **merge and compact***? (now i sound like google)

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)?